# Select para exibir o nome das colunas de uma tabela?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

**Tabelas**

```
col1| col2| col3| ...| coln
 1  |  2  |  3  | ...|  n
```

**Exibir o nome :**

> ```
> col1
> col2
> col3
> ...
> coln
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que pro oracle você precisa usar o `all_tab_cols`, veja:

```
SELECT 
    column_name
FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'tabela'
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2093.htm

Comment: Sua resposta faz sentido, mas uma referência seria bem vinda

Answer (score 1):

Esta function é útil para desenvolvedores pois gera uma lista editável para SQL

```
create or replace FUNCTION colunas (TABELA  IN USER_TABLES.TABLE_NAME%TYPE,
                                    PREFIXO IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                    SUFIXO  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  VS_SAI VARCHAR2(4000);
  /*GERA LISTA COM AS COLUNAS DE UMA TABELA*/
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
            FROM   USER_TAB_COLUMNS
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = TABELA
            ORDER BY COLUMN_ID)
  LOOP
    VS_SAI := VS_SAI || PREFIXO || R.COLUMN_NAME || SUFIXO ||',';
  END LOOP;
  VS_SAI := SUBSTR(VS_SAI,1,LENGTH(VS_SAI)-1);
  RETURN VS_SAI;
END;
```

Faça :

select colunas('') from dual